# iOS Custom video trimmer UI

Tags: ios, video, edit

I'm trying to make a video editing app and for that I need to create a video timeline where I will put different views depending on the amount of videos that are being editing and their longitude.

[image: timeline view]

For now, what I have in my timeline view is a scrollview and inside a stackview which contain a uiview for each video in the composition. The width of each uiview has a dynamic size depending on the duration of their represented videos.

If I select a video (uiview) and I drag it by the left or the right I reduce the uiview width and the video duration (and start time if it is by the left).

The problem with that is that if I trim the video by the left, the animation looks awkward because the uiview is narrowed by the right due to the scrollView/stackView solution.

[image: narrow view by right when I drag by left]

I'm almost sure that this is not the best way to face this but no other solutions come to my mind.

Do you know another way to do this or how to solve my problem with the trim?